# What do you get from Shovelstrike Quarry?

Tags: animal-crossing-pocket-camp

There's the Shovelstrike Quarry, but it costs me tickets or friends' help to access it.

What do you get from Shovelstrike quarry? Is it worth the 20 tickets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information is available in Isabelle's Beginner's guide 'Visiting the Quarry'.

You need 5 friends or 20 leaf tickets to enter.
You earn bells and crafting materials by finding minerals in the quarry.